# Dataframe - How to sort value of one column without changing index and other columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

```
print(df)

        0          1     2
5   354.7      blabl   8.0
4    55.4     Auddat   4.0
2   176.5   Decezefr  12.0
```

output expected :

```
        0          1     2
5   354.7      blabl   4.0
4    55.4     Auddat   8.0
2   176.5   Decezefr  12.0
```

I tried with those following lines without many succes..

```
df_data['monotone_s_va']=df_data['monotone_s_va'].sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=False , kind='quicksort', ignore_index=True)
```

or

```
df_data['monotone_s_va']=df_data['monotone_s_va'].sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=False , kind='quicksort', ignore_index=False)
```

Does sb have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**UPDATED**)

**First way:**

You can replace the column you want to sort (along the lines of the attempts you included in your question) like this:

```py
df['monotone_s_va'] = df['monotone_s_va'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Second way:**

Here is another way to do what your question asks, based on the sample df shown in your question with numeric column labels:

```py
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=2), df.loc[:,2].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0,1,2], data = [
[354.7,'blabl',8.0],
[55.4,'Auddat',4.0],
[176.5,'Decezefr',12.0]])
print(df)

df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=2), df.loc[:,2].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
       0         1     2
0  354.7     blabl   8.0
1   55.4    Auddat   4.0
2  176.5  Decezefr  12.0
```

Output:

```
       0         1     2
0  354.7     blabl   4.0
1   55.4    Auddat   8.0
2  176.5  Decezefr  12.0
```

Note: If the name of the column to be sorted is `monotone_s_va` as your question seems to suggest, you can replace the key line with this:

```py
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='monotone_s_va'), df['monotone_s_va'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

**UPDATE #2**: Here is a way to preserve the index of the original dataframe while sorting just one column, as reflected in OP's update to the original question.

```py
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='monotone_s_va'), df['monotone_s_va'].sort_values().to_frame().assign(index=df.index).set_index('index')], axis=1)
```

Input:

```
       0         1  monotone_s_va
5  354.7     blabl            8.0
4   55.4    Auddat            4.0
2  176.5  Decezefr           12.0
```

Output:

```
       0         1  monotone_s_va
5  354.7     blabl            4.0
4   55.4    Auddat            8.0
2  176.5  Decezefr           12.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just changed the example. I have some issue with index that are sorted. I would like to sort only the values. In my real case they are timestamps

Comment: I found this way :)

df_data['monotone_s_va'] = df_data.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).values)['monotone_s_va']

Comment: Ordinarily, protocol suggests asking a new question rather than changing an existing one after it has been answered, but as your changes are not extreme, I will update my answer to address them. In any case, please consider marking this answer as accepted, since it's original version successfully addressed your question prior to the changes you made.

Comment: @Thomas LESIEUR Do you need any additional help? If not, please consider marking this answer as accepted, assuming it has addressed both your original question and your follow-up question.